# Relation "auth_user_entity" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using typeORM and i have an AuthUserEnity

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class AuthUserEntity  {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number; 

   @Column()
    public email :string;

   @Column()
    public password :string;

    @Column()
    public salt : string
}
```

and in AppModule

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { AuthUserEntity } from "./auth/auth.user.entity";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";




@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
                port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
                username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
                password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
                entities: [AuthUserEntity],
                synchronized: true
            })
        }),
        AuthModule
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: []
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

In AuthModule, i have :

```
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AuthUserEntity])]
```

I'm try to you postman to post data and I'm getting an error " relation "auth_user_entity" does not exist"
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks very muchh !

Comment: Did you create / run migration for it?